# Fixed header, footer and infinite scroll: is it possible?

Tags: jquery, html, css

At the moment my site has a fixed header and infinite scroll. But as soon as I introduce a fixed footer, the infinite scroll switches off and turns to page navigation. Is it possible to have all three?

I tried various sticky footers available online as well as combing this site for solutions. They all work - until I scroll and then it suddenly disappears. The code below is the only one so far that has stayed put.

Apologies in advance - I am trying to learn. All feedback much appreciated.

Also, I made a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LLfhp/1/)

-

For the fixed footer, I used -

```
<div class="row">
<div class="column grid_12">
<div id="wrap">
<div id="footer" class="footer">
    APPLY </div>
```

This for the css -

```
.footer {
 clear: both;
position: fixed;
color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
opacity: 0.3;
height: 35px;
overflow: hidden;
display: block;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%; 
}
.footer ul{
margin:0;
padding:0;
list-style:none;
text-align:center;
} 

.footer ul li {
margin:0 5px;
display:inline-block;
}

.footer ul li a{
padding:10px;
background:#555;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
}

 .footer ul li a:hover{
  background:#888;
   }
```

This for the JS -

```
   var footerHeight = 0,
    footerTop = 0,
    $footer = $("#footer");
positionFooter();

function positionFooter() {

    footerHeight = $footer.outerHeight(); // changed
    footerTop = ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() - footerHeight) + "px";

    if (($(document.body).height() + footerHeight) < $(window).height()) {
        $footer.css({
            position: "absolute"
        }).animate({
            top: footerTop
        }, -1)
    } else {
        $footer.css({
            position: "static"
        })
    }
}

$(window).scroll(positionFooter).resize(positionFooter)

});
```

Comment: Your fiddle is not giving any output

Comment: It gives output, the footer color is white >.>

Comment: Well, slightly opaque :)

Comment: Can you give an example of the working version without the footer as well?

Comment: @ Zach Saucier, yes, here: http://tinyurl.com/o46hj3b